# any way to let 2 sub-programs to talk each other?

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes

Can these 2 nodes, someway, talk each other? Or a sub-program is only an end stage?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I still have to fully understand the dynamic behind these cool sub-programs..

Is maybe necessary creating something that stand "on the middle"? like a script by the sub-program, don't know....

---

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to automate the position of the scotch according to the position of the picture's vertices, the way I've done yet with the pictures and the picture's paper to the vertices of a grid :)

I just miss the scotch.. I searching a way to use the vertices by the looping sub-program...

A little difficult to explain, I know ^^"

[image: paintings]

[image]

e.thing red after linking..

[image: red]

the 2 subprograms I'm trying to connect. I need the position of those vertexes..

[image: when linking]

Comment: subprograms can have outputs that you can plug into the next subprogram. I'm not sure what you want to archieve here..

Comment: It gives back errors when doing that.. a sub-program can't link to another sub-program, as it says in the animation node tree's tool (T) menù once these have been linked..

Comment: Two subprograms can't be in one network, that is true. But you can invoke a subprogram from another subprogram. Hard to explain now. Could maybe explain what you want to archieve?

Comment: difficult to explain too.. ^^" I added an edit to the question with more details, hope It helps..

Comment: I wonder why you need this little loop on the right. Maybe a normal Object Transforms Output node would be enouph. The Object Mesh Data node on the right outputs a list of vertices. Do you need all these locations or just one? If you'd need them all it wouldn't make sense to apply them all to the same object...

Comment: I've not performed that yet.. I need next to separate the object into 4 singularities and so align to the 4 respective vertices of the image texture. I need all the vertexes, 4 scotch for picture, 245 pictures.. And I need to move them in future, this actually works by the grid, It salved me a lot of time.. the problem here is just the scotch.. But I will probably duplicate all the planes and use then as a group and so will link to a brand new loop sub-program.. I tested and works that way but I'm searching a more dynamic way to do that (without duplicating the 245 planes and create a group)..

Comment: I left nodes with holes because I need to replicate the situation.. I'd like to proceed the way I linked as pics but It doesn't work.. :)

Comment: hm not sure if I can help you with the project here on stackexchange.. sorry.  Maybe you should ask this in the Animation Nodes thread on BlenderArtists. The question is a bit too unspecifc to answer it in a single post..

Comment: Please provide a more specific guide on what you are trying to achieve and how are you trying to achieve it.

Comment: Look at Looch's solar system animation tutorial.  I'm thinking that perhaps you could use a group and use the Group Input and Invoke Subprogram on the group as a way to feed stuff across different animation nodes networks.  See my query about this in the  on blenderartists forums AN thread. http://lollypopman.com/2016/04/02/tutorial-an-solar-system/

Comment: groups seems the answer! gonna take a test and report back ASAP!!! thanks for the precious time of all of You so far!! :]